# How to redirect post request to other url in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to redirect a post request from one server to another server with additional parameters from request 1. You can check the below code.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/pay1',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req._body);
    console.log(req.body); // output {'a':'value'}
    req.body['new']='other';
    console.log(req._body);
    console.log(req.body); // {'a':'value','new':"other"}
    res.redirect(307,'/pay2');
});

app.post('/pay2',(req,res)=>{
// this request will be in other server, for now I am testing in same server
    console.log(req.body); // output {'a':'value'}
    res.send('2dsaf');
});
```

How to pass extra fields to other request?

Comment: If you want to send parameters with a redirect, put them in as query parameters and then have the redirected route parse them from there.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have to send those extra parameters from post request only. That is a third party service and data which has to be sent to that server has to be secured(should not be available in front-end).

Comment: Well, a redirect is just a header with a new URL in it so trying to add to `req.body` won't have anything to do with a subsequent request from the browser.  The browser won't even know about it.  So, you have to find a different way to solve whatever it is you're trying to solve.  You might get better help if you describe the high level problem you're trying to solve rather than a question about a detailed implementation that won't work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 307 response says the request should be repeated to the new URL with the same method, but there is no way for you to change the request body the browser will send.

If you could use GET instead, you would be able to change the parameters (since they are part of the request path).

You could instead proxy the request, by sending it freshly to the new server from your server side, and pass the response back to your client. If you do things this way, you would be able to change the body however you like.

Another option would be to instead respond with an HTML page encoding the posted data in hidden form fields, plus the fields you wanted to add, and have the user click a submit button. You'd point the form's action at the other server.

Answer (score 0):

I could do this to my code and all working just add new parameters and parse it there

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/pay1',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req._body);
    console.log(req.body); // output {'a':'value'}
    req.body['new']='other';
    console.log(req._body);
    console.log(req.body); // {'a':'value','new':"other"}
    res.redirect(307,'/pay2?a=value');
});

app.post('/pay2',(req,res)=>{
// this request will be in other server, for now I am testing in same server
    console.log(req.query.a + req.query.whatever //Whatever you have in the first request too); // output {'a':'value'}
    res.send('2dsaf');
});
```

Comment: this can be done if the second server is ours. But here the second server is of the third party, they will not use query params for retrieving data.

Comment: Oh My bad didn't notice